# React - useMemo giving warning although program is running fine. (useMemo has an unnecessary dependency)

Tags: reactjs, react-usememo

First of all sorry for bad code. I am new to React, so please excuse me :P. Here I have created 2 buttons, "add" and "Change fake". When I click on "add" it will not re-render child component and when I click on "change fake", It does re-render the component because my dependency has changed in useMemo and it creates and sends a new object props to child. But I am getting a warning for useMemo saying it's an unnecessary dependency although I need to dependency. How can I go that warning go away. Is there a better way to do this?

Note: My child component is a dummy component. It does not do anything with those props.

```
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const fakeValue = useRef(10);

  const randomProp = useMemo(() => {
    return { val: fakeValue.current };
  }, [fakeValue.current]);

  const changeFake = () => {
    fakeValue.current = fakeValue.current + 1;
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <div>{fakeValue.current}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>add</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeFake()}>Change fake</button>
      <Child randomProp={randomProp} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Output link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5spw1.png
CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-pine-fzjw9?file=/src/

Maybe a dumb question. But I would appreciate some feedback from the community please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `fakeValue.current` ref directly into dependency of `useMemo` it will not change value of `randomProp`. then child component wont `re-render`.
So you need to do something like this.

```
const randomValue = fakeValue.current;

  const randomProp = useMemo(() => {
    return { val: randomValue };
  }, [randomValue]);
```

If re-render not required, just want to remove the warning, you can remove `fakeValue.current` dependency

CodeSandbox link modified code : https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-thunder-9ylxi?file=/src/Parent.js

Comment: When fakeValue.current is changing it is re-rendering the component. But only thing is that I'm getting that warning. But I see if I store it in seperate variable and then pass that variable the error no longer exist. Thanks for that. Still I feel it's weird that if we pass fakeValue.current it gives warning even though it's working completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

`fakeValue.current` is an unnecessary dependency because mutating it does not re-render the component. We do not add *references* as dependencies.

You can remove the warning by adding an empty array as a dependency to `useMemo`.

```js
const randomProp = useMemo(() => {
  return { val: fakeValue.current };
}, []); // Pass an empty array like this
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/usememo-warning-67955446-5x8j3

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: But now the problem is when fakeValue.current changes I want my child to re-render. If I pass empty array. It won't re-render the child even though fakeValue.current changed

Comment: If you want to re-render the component then the only recommended way is to create a state and update it.

Comment: Also, I recommend you to refer to [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) before using hooks like useMemo.

Comment: Thanks Yushan. Will check that out. I'm new to React and I get these weird scenarios while trying different things out :P